# Are we allowed to ask questions about the nintendo Smash Bros poll?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

Recently there has been a big fire sweeping the internet regarding an [official poll](https://cp.nintendo.co.jp/us/) by Nintendo asking fans which characters they'd like to see in Smash Bros.

This is exciting, but it also raises a lot of legitimate and interesting questions, and before we start seeing an influx of them, I'd like to know if questions about this *at all* are on-topic or acceptable for this site.

Obvioulsy questions like "which characters would Nintendo accept" or "how will characters be implemented from the poll" would be unaccepted, since they're about developer intent.  And questions just asking "who did you vote for" would be off-topic because they're not really SE questions. But in particular, I'd like to know who's ahead in the polls, and whether or not multiple poll votes are being counted from the same IP, which might be answerable questions.

But, before I can ask if either of *those* are answerable questions, I'd like to know if questions about this poll are on-topic or accepted **at all*, since this entire poll could be considered 'developer intent' based.

So, not going into specific questions that are/aren't answerable, are questions about the Smash Poll valid questions for this site?

Comment: I don't see what viable questions could be asked about the poll anyways. "What did you vote for" is opinion-based and "is Character X allowed" is probably developer intent.

Comment: Though the close reason no longer exists, "Who's ahead in the polls" would likely be far too localized to a specific period of time to be useful.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm inclined to say we don't want these questions. They're about an ongoing internet poll, and not **about videogames or videogame consoles within the scope defined in the [help center](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)** in any but the most loosely defined and casual way.